# Generating srcset in a similar way to WordPress

Tags: craft3, assets, image, responsive-images

I come from a WordPress background, so I'm attempting to create responsive images the way I'm accustomed to with WordPress.  Perhaps that's the wrong approach, I'm not sure.

In WordPress I would define five images size: `thumbnail`, `medium`, `medium_large`, `large`, `XL` and I would specify a width for each.  Typically I would define the widths as `414`, `768`, `1024`, `1600` and `1920` pixels respectively.  For the `sizes` attribute I would specify this manually on an image-by-image basis.

Outputting an image would look like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'large' ); ?>"
     srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id ); ?>" />
```

The above would output all 5 image sizes to the `srcset` attribute.

So, back to Craft.  I have setup 5 asset transforms under `Settings` using the same handles as above.  I believe you can also set these up progmatically too.

I can then output each of my image sizes in the following way:

```
{% set image = entry.aboutImage.withTransforms(['thumbnail', 'medium', 'mediumLarge', 'large', 'xl']).first() %}

<img src="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" alt=""
     srcset="{{ image.getUrl('xl') }} {{ image.getWidth('xl') }}w,
             {{ image.getUrl('large') }} {{ image.getWidth('large') }}w,
             {{ image.getUrl('mediumLarge') }} {{ image.getWidth('mediumLarge') }}w,
             {{ image.getUrl('medium') }} {{ image.getWidth('medium') }}w,
             {{ image.getUrl('thumbnail') }} {{ image.getWidth('thumbnail') }}w"
     width="{{ image.getWidth() }}" height="{{ image.getHeight() }}" />
```

Whilst this works okay, it's kind of cumbersome to repeat this for every image. Also, if the user uploads a very small image then I'm guessing it won't be available in all sizes.

I noticed that there is also this method:

```
{{ asset.getImg({ width: 300, height: 300 }, ['1.5x', '2x', '3x']) }}
```

However I'd like to do the following, which doesn't work:

```
{{ asset.getImg({ width: 300, height: 300 }, ['thumbnail', 'medium', 'mediumLarge', 'large', 'xl']) }}
```

I've read about `macros` but so far haven't really been able to fathom out how I'd achieve the above using a macro, or it it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function, a utility template or a macro to make repetitive tasks like generating responsive images easier. I usually prefer templates, because they're easy to extend and they can take a lot of optional arguments without the user needing to pass all of them.

Building your own utility templates is a good time investments, since you can create a set of parameters / options into the template that you can use wherever you want to display images in your templates.

For example, here's a simple responsive image template that will take an image asset and a list of transforms and output an `<img>` tag:

```twig
{# utils/responsive-image.twig #}
{%- set transforms = transforms|default([]) -%}
{%- set transformedImages = transforms|map(transform => image.copyWithTransform(transform)) -%}
{%- set srcset = transformedImages|map(image => "#{image.getUrl()} #{image.width}w") -%}
{%- set attributes = attributes ?? {} -%}

<img {{ attr(attributes|merge({ srcset: srcset|join(', '), })) }}>
```

Since this template accepts a list of [transforms](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#public-methods), you can pass it any parameters that are accepted by [Asset.getUrl()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#public-methods). So both named transforms and hashes will work:

```twig
{% set image = entry.header_image.one() %}
{{ include('utils/responsive-image', {
    image: image,
    transforms: [{ width: 300, height: 300 }, { width: 600, height: 600 }],
}, with_context = false) }}
```

```twig
{% set image = entry.header_image.one() %}
{{ include('utils/responsive-image', {
    image: image,
    transforms: ['thumbnail', 'medium', 'mediumLarge'],
}, with_context = false) }}
```

Note the utility template also includes an optional parameter to specify additional attributes for the `<img>` tag. Here's a complete example:

```twig
{% set image = entry.header_image.one() %}
{{ include('utils/responsive-image', {
    image: image,
    transforms: [
        { width: 300, height: 300, mode: 'crop', position: 'top-center'},
        { width: 600, height: 600 }
    ],
    attributes: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        srcset: '(min-width: 300px) 300px, 100vw',
        class: 'my-responsive-image',
    },
}, with_context = false) }}
```

Once you have the basic setup in place, you can expand your utility template to handle more repetitive tasks for you. For example, my utility template for responsive images can:

- Generate a `<picture>` with multiple sources.
- Automatically generate alternative `<source>` tags with WebP images.
- Apply a fixed aspect ratio to all transforms.
- Handle SVGs gracefully.
- Take the `alt` text from the asset's `alt` field, if it exists.
- … and much more.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd be very interested to see the full version of your img template if you'd like to share it...

Comment: @JamesSmith Sorry, I developed that template for work, so I can't share it in full. But its a good exercise to develop your own starting with something small like my example here and then add features/parameters as they come up. It also really depends on how you build your templates and how you usually incorporate images, so what you end up with could focus on totally different aspects than my utility template!

Comment: This is really cool @MoritzLost - Can I ask, how would you place the mode? As im trying to crop with a specific focal point but am not clear on how to achieve this outcome

Comment: @Wally If you use the `transforms` parameter as in the starter template above, you can just include `crop` and `mode` in the [transform definition](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html#defining-transforms-in-your-templates). I've updated the usage example code to include those parameters. In the full version of the utility template I use for my projects, both of those can be passed as optional parameters as well and are automatically merged into the transforms if passed.

Comment: @MoritzLost amazing like always!

Comment: @MoritzLost Any chance you could share your code with the picture element?

Comment: @CreateSean I can't share the full template as it's part of commercial projects. But I would recommend building utility templates like those yourself anyway, this is the only way they're gonna make sense to you and fit your use-case. My utility template can output a `<picture>` element with multiple `<source>` elements – it does that by accepting a `sources` variable that holds an array of `transform` definitions as well as some additional parameters (`media`, `width`, `height`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Craft has a newer asset method called [getSrcset](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html#generating-srcset-sizes) which should be close to what you need. Here's the code example from the docs:

```
{% do asset.setTransform({ width: 300, height: 300 }) %}
{{ tag('img', {
  src: asset.url,
  width: asset.width,
  height: asset.height,
  srcset: asset.getSrcset(['1.5x', '2x', '3x']),
  alt: asset.title,
}) }}
```

You can also skip the transform and use explicit widths (rather than the 1x, 2x variants) like this:

```
{{ tag('img', {
  src: asset.url,
  width: asset.width,
  height: asset.height,
  srcSet: asset.getSrcset(['414w', '768w', '1024w', '1600w', '1920w']),
  alt: asset.title,
}) }}
```

Assuming you already have transforms set for those sizes, it should use the same rendered images.

And if you wanted to skip the `src` tag for some reason, you could write it like this:

```
<img src="asset.url"
  width="asset.width"
  height="asset.height"
  srcSet="asset.getSrcset(['414w', '768w', '1024w', '1600w', '1920w'])"
  alt="asset.title"
/>
```

Comment: That's useful, and close to what I'm looking for.  The downside is if I change my 414 transform to say 480, then I have to find and replace all instances of it, rather than being able to reference it by name, i.e. `thumbnail`

Comment: Yeah we don’t use many named transforms so that typically hasn’t been a problem in our case. We just generate them on the fly whenever the template is rendered and then the transformed assets are cached for future use.